# SerialPort encoding - I need 8-Bit ASCII or a hint

Tags: encoding, ascii

I need your help. I am trying to implement a data-readout between a c# serialport application and a microcontroller.

A little Example:

My Microcontroller is sending 32-Bit Integers in 4 8-Byte values.

on my microcontroller the code is looking like that:

```
uart_putc((uint8_t)(number>>24));
uart_putc((uint8_t)(number>>16));
uart_putc((uint8_t)(number>>8));
uart_putc((uint8_t)number);
```

uart_putc(char c) is afunction that sends one character via the serialport

When i have a number like:

```
uint32_t number = 16000000;
```

the microcontroller is splitting and sending this number with the code above into these 4 parts:

- 0
- 244
- 36
- 0

This is validated by a Terminal program. In C# I want to put this number together again.
I used the function

```
byte[] asciiBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string);
```

but it doesn't work properly, because it converts only a 7 Byte integer and 244 for example ist more than it.
Can you help me with my problem? I dont want to convert the numbero n the microcontroller into a string and reconvert the string into a number in my c# application due to performance.

Thanks very much!

PS:

Got it!

The problem was, that the encoding BEFORE the readout of the serialport buffer was wrong.

```
System.Text.Encoding iso_8859_1 = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
port.Encoding = iso_8859_1;
```

solved my problem!

Thanks anyway ;)

Comment: [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) only defines 128 characters (i.e. 7 bits)

Comment: write a solution, explain it there and then accept it. that way (1) the thread comes to a logical conclusion (2) any other person may be benefited.